# How do I add an Example Project to a Flutter Package?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

Is there a way to autogenerate template code for the example map structure in a package?

Most packages have a /example folder within the package root that showcases the package functionality.
I'm not sure what's the "best" way to create the example is, or if it even matter.

Do I create all files individually?
Do I create a new  project and then copy it to the package root?
Can I autogenerate an example project directly in the project?

It's my first attempt on creating a package and I want to get it right the first time.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To create a Flutter package with an Example in Android Studio

1. Create a new Flutter Project
   [image]
2. Select Flutter Package
   [image]
3. After the new project opens in Android Studio, select the "Terminal" tab and then run:

> **flutter create example**

[image]

4. Select "Edit Configuration"-> add configuration -> Select the main.dart file that is located in the example/lib folder
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
5. Open your example pubspec.yaml and link to the library by adding:

   your_package_name:
   path: ..\
   [image]

NOTE: When you open the Example folder it will look like an entire Flutter app nested into your project; that's because it is. Just open the io and android folders to see that they share that pattern:
[image]

Comment: This is probably the best answer I have seen on stackoverflow.
Thank You 

Comment: This was way better than my own answer. Moved the correct answer to this and hope that the people who's looking for a quick answer finds the old one bellow.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped

Comment: Just to complement this, from the cmd line: To create package:`flutter create package [packagname]`.
To create example: cd into the package then`flutter create example`

Comment: And this is how any answer should be posted here in SO. Simple, direct and clear.

Answer (score 20):

Create a new project inside the root directory of your project called example and then remove unnecessary files such as `CHANGELOG`, `LICENSE` and `README` as they will be in your package folder.

Here's an example (no pun intended) with a package that I created:

[image]
[image]

Now in `pubspec.yaml` you should include your package as dev dependency like this:

```
dev_dependencies:
  your_package:
    path: ../
```

I believe you can also use regular dependencies, but this worked for me.

Now inside `/lib` you can add a `main.dart` file, import your package and then create an example project.

Comment: Just to clarify, go to your project root folder and run `flutter create example`.
Thats it.

Comment: @JoelBroström By the way, you could keep the `README` inside the example project, for the Example tab on pub.dev, but otherwise it will just show the code.

Comment: @JoelBroström Please add this as an answer, not a response

Comment: Did as you said. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 17):

Go to your project root folder and run `flutter create example`.
Thats it.

Answer (score 9):

Use the built-in **flutter** command-line tool in the root directory of the project to do all the work:

```
/e/projects/myproject # flutter create example
```

which has this output:

```
Creating project example... androidx: true
  example\.gitignore (created)
  example\.idea\libraries\Dart_SDK.xml (created)
  example\.idea\libraries\Flutter_for_Android.xml (created)
  example\.idea\libraries\KotlinJavaRuntime.xml (created)
  example\.idea\modules.xml (created)
  example\.idea\runConfigurations\main_dart.xml (created)
  example\.idea\workspace.xml (created)
  example\.metadata (created)
  example\android\app\build.gradle (created)
  example\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\example\example\MainActivity.kt (created)
  example\android\build.gradle (created)
  example\android\example_android.iml (created)
  example\android\.gitignore (created)
  example\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml (created)
  example\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml (created)
  example\android\app\src\main\res\drawable\launch_background.xml (created)
  example\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
  example\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
  example\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
  example\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
  example\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
  example\android\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml (created)
  example\android\app\src\profile\AndroidManifest.xml (created)
  example\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties (created)
  example\android\gradle.properties (created)
  example\android\settings.gradle (created)
  example\ios\Runner\AppDelegate.swift (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Runner-Bridging-Header.h (created)
  example\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\project.pbxproj (created)
  example\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\xcshareddata\xcschemes\Runner.xcscheme (created)
  example\ios\.gitignore (created)
  example\ios\Flutter\AppFrameworkInfo.plist (created)
  example\ios\Flutter\Debug.xcconfig (created)
  example\ios\Flutter\Release.xcconfig (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Contents.json (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-1024x1024@1x.png (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@1x.png (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@2x.png (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@3x.png (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@1x.png (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@2x.png (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@3x.png (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@1x.png (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@2x.png (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@3x.png (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-60x60@2x.png (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-60x60@3x.png (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-76x76@1x.png (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-76x76@2x.png (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\Contents.json (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\LaunchImage.png (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\LaunchImage@2x.png (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\LaunchImage@3x.png (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\README.md (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Base.lproj\LaunchScreen.storyboard (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Base.lproj\Main.storyboard (created)
  example\ios\Runner\Info.plist (created)
  example\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\project.xcworkspace\contents.xcworkspacedata (created)
  example\ios\Runner.xcworkspace\contents.xcworkspacedata (created)
  example\lib\main.dart (created)
  example\example.iml (created)
  example\pubspec.yaml (created)
  example\README.md (created)
  example\test\widget_test.dart (created)
Running "flutter pub get" in example...                             3.0s
Wrote 68 files.

All done!
[√] Flutter: is fully installed. (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices: is fully installed. (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Android Studio: is fully installed. (version 3.5)
[√] Connected device: is fully installed. (2 available)

In order to run your application, type:

  $ cd example
  $ flutter run

Your application code is in example\lib\main.dart.
```

If using Android Studio 3.5.2, run the default example for assurance:

1. Add a new configuration for the example main.dart by selecting *Edit Configurations...* from the Flutter drop-down on the toolbar.
2. Select the Flutter directory on the left of the *Run/Debug Configurations* dialog and press the *+* button.
3. Select *Flutter*
4. Browse for main.dart in the new example/lib directory by clicking the file folder in the *Dart entrypoint:* dialog.
5. Click the triangle run button on the toolbar.

I just performed these steps for my own project and it worked perfectly.

Then, to customize for your project, edit the example's **pubspec.yaml** file and add a dependency to your project:

```
dependencies:
  my_project:
    path: ../
```

Answer (score 0):

*In my case , I had forgot to add the example file . I added this in this way.*
You can check at my pub.dev [location_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/location_provider) package.

1)Create a directory/package inside you package . Name of package/directory must be "**example**". For more info [***check this.***](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/package-layout#examples)

2)Open command Terminal and move inside the ***example*** package using

```
cd example
```

3)Create Flutter project inside it using command

```
Flutter create
```

4)You will see the ***lib/main.dart*** file inside it. Add your example in this file.

5)After adding , push latest code to the github.

6)Increase the version of  your package inside ***pubspec.yaml*** file and ***CHELLAGELOG.md*** file . After that, run these command to publish the package to ***pub.dev***.

```
Flutter publish --dry-run
Flutter publish
```

*After that you will see ,example Tab in* ***pub.dev***

Answer (score 0):

If you have fvm setup then

```
fvm flutter create --template=package upr_ride_reservation_bloc
```

If you don't have fvm then

```
flutter create --template=package package name
```